# Bluebird for parallel independent tasks

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bluebird, es6-promise

Say I want to send a email and push a notification to the client at the same time after lookup a user from database, I could write

```
User.findById(userId).exec()
.then(() => sendMail())
.then(() => pushNotification())
```

but, since the `pushNotification` doesn't have to happen after `sendMail`, is there any other way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var BlueBird = require('bluebird');

User.findById(userId).exec()
    .then(() => Bluebird.all([sendMail(), pushNotification()]))
```

would start them both at the same time and wait for them both.

Answer (score 0):

Same with es6:

```
User.findById(userId).exec()
  .then(() => Promise.all([sendMail(), pushNotification()]))
```